# Why isn't $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ integrally closed?

Tags: commutative-algebra

The book I'm reading casually mention that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ isn't integrally closed without explaining why.  Could someone show me why this is the case?

Comment: Because the golden ratio $\,\varphi = (1\!+\!\sqrt{5})/2\,$ is a root of $\,x^2-x-1\ $ so the Rational Root Test fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ (hence over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$) and is contained in the field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, but is not contained in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.

In general, the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ if $d\equiv 2,3$ (mod $4$), and is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$ if $d\equiv 1$ (mod $4$).